# Partially overlapping random and fixed effects in glmer

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have a logistic mixed model, where I look at the effect of two conditions over  accuracy (% correct) for different subjects.

```
glmres = glmer(accuracy ~ condition + (1|subject), data = myData, family = binomial)
```

All subjects saw the same 100 stimuli (words), but the experimental condition these words belonged to depended on the subject. So for example, for some subjects word A belonged to condition C1 and word B belonged to condition C2. For some subjects it was the other way around. The words were drawn from a bigger pool so I think I should include them as a random effect.

The problem is, the correspondence between words and conditions could not be (precisely) controlled and it is the case that for *most* subjects (about 70:30, depending on the word), A belonged to condition C1.
This means that the fixed effect `condition` and the (potential) random effect `(1|word)` are not completely independent.

My question is whether it would be incorrect to include two non-independent effects (where one is fixed, one is random). As a result of this dependency (I think) my results change a lot according to whether I include the random effect or not.

Comment: In what way do the results *change a lot* ? Also, what difference(s) do you get between using `(1|word)` and `(1|condition:word`) ?

Comment: I thought you only have 2 conditions, C1 and C2 ?

Comment: Yes, but I simplified the question to post it here. The model is more complex, I have two fixed effects, but only one of them is partially dependent on the random effect. Would it be very different with a more complex model?

Comment: If you only have 2 conditions them you can't use condition as a random effect.

Comment: Ach, sorry, sorry! I was distracted when I wrote the comment. As I said in the post I want to include `subject` and `word` as random effects. Really sorry for the confusion. I will edit the comment above, hoping it won't be chaotic

Comment: Doing `(1|subject:word)` gives me very similar values than when I do `(1|subject)` actually. But if I do `(1|subject)` + `(1|word)` I get about 2-fold difference in estimates and rather big differences in z values (which lead p values changing from <0.001 to >.05). But I guess this last option is wrong?

Comment: I didn't suggest `(1|subject:word)`, that would make no sense. I suggested `(1|condition:word) ` and asked how that compared with `(1|word)` ?

Comment: I see (I hope..).  `glmfit1 <- correct ~ condition + (1 | condition:word)` vs `glmfit2 <- correct ~ condition + (1 | word)` (and also the versions including ` + (1|subject)`  differ in estimate value, about 4-fold in AIC/BIC and in p-values from p < 1^-16 to p=0.002. They don't differ in a model comparison, but the conclusions are different. Hope this answers your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43769/discussion-between-robert-long-and-elisa).